# What is the difference between "belehren" and "lehren"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, prefix, connotation

I realize many verbs add the "be" to the beginning, which fundamentally changes the meaning, e.g., *kommen* and *bekommen*, or *stehen* and *bestehen*. However, it seems as though the "be" in *belehren* doesn't change the meaning much, if at all. So when should I use it?

Comment: also see:http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4246/how-to-say-thank-you-for-teaching-me-that-word-in-german

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with you that it doesn't change the meaning that much...

> jemanden etwas lehren

means to teach something to somebody.
So you'd be building up new knowledge by teaching them.

Whereas

> jemanden belehren

in most cases means that you're correcting somebody who thinks he knows, but is not really correct.
So you'd be straightening his facts.

One other use of *belehren* would be that you inform somebody of something.
An example would be if you tell them about their rights ("*You have the right to remain silent...*")
In that case it would be

> jemanden über seine Rechte belehren

---

So to sum up, with *lehren* you're kind of teaching or providing knowledge to somebody.

With *belehren* you're rather telling somebody something than you're teaching.
So you're doing that probably with more resolution and authority.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel danke für den Hinweis, ich habe es korrigiert.

Answer (score 7):

There is a grammatical difference and a difference in meaning...

**belehren**

**Belehren** takes a person as a direct object in accusative case. If you want to include whatever is being taught that is done using the preposition **über** or **hinsichtlich**

> Ich belehre den Mann über die Sache.

**Belehren** has a notion of completion... at least more than lehren has. After having been **belehrt,** I expect the person to know everything about the matter.
Also, **belehren** is done with rather limited fields of knowledge. It is one specific thing that is being taught... like a code of conduct or the late fees of the library. So you can't really belehren someone about biology... I wouldn't know how to understand the following sentence:

> Ich belehre dich über Biologie.

This is so vague that it could be anything... but it certainly is not the biological knowledge itself.
**Belehren** also has a negative touch to it... I wouldn't appreciate being **belehrt**. I'd prefer to be **informiert.**

**lehren**

**Lehren** can take 2 direct accusative objects... the thing being taught and the person being taught.

> Ich lehre Klavier.
>
> Der Professor hat mich die Liebe gelehrt.

**Lehren** doesn't imply completion. It can but it doesn't have to. It can be a life long process. It is also the word for the profession... to teach.
Also lehren is not negative sounding. It is pretty neutral.
In daily life, I think **lehren** as a verb is on the decline. I find it kind of weird in a sentence and I would opt for **unterrichten**.
However, the nouns derived from **lehren** are totally part of everyday talk. Lehrer, Lehrling, Lehrplan, Lehrbuch, Lehrfilm, Lehrvideo, Lehrgang...

Comment: I have wondered about this for so long. Thanks for the great response.

Comment: "Belehren" hat keinen negatven Touch. Ein negativer Beigeschmack kann immer nur aus dem Kontext kommen, in der die Belehrung stattfindet, und in einem solchen gibt es den Belehrer, den Belehrten, eventuell Beobachter und weitere Personen, die die Situation alle unterschiedlich bewerten können. Wir sollten wirklich von dieser Illusion wegkommen, dass das nächstbeste Beispiel, dass uns zu einem Begriff einfällt, diesen prototypisch beschreibt, und eingebildete Gefühle zu dem Begriff, und nicht zu unseren Vorurteilen gehören. `Die Mutter belehrte Hänschen von Steckdosen fern zu bleiben.`

Comment: Siehe auch @Lukas Kommentar über die Belehrung des Angeklagten über seine Rechte. Aus welcher Perspektive ist das negativ? Entschuldige, dass ich es so deutlich sage, aber die unreife Tendenz alles immer bewerten zu wollen ist eine Seuche.

Comment: Sorry aber für mich klingt belehren nun mal leicht negativ... Ich werde nicht gern belehrt, aber ich habe kein Problem damit wenn man mich etwas lehrt.
Die gefühlsmässige Bewertung eines Wortes spielt natürlich mit rein und ist für Deutschlernende wichtig um zu verstehen in welchen Kontexten das Wort angebracht ist und wo nicht. Das da die Meinungen auseinandergehen ist normal, aber ich denke ich gehe kein großes Risiko ein,w enn ich behaupte, dass eine Mehrheit der Deutschen belehren als nefativer klingend einstufen würde als lehren...

Comment: @Emanuel Und was würde anlernen dann heißen? Klingt "jemanden etwas anleren" auch negativ so wie belehren?

Comment: @Jonhy *Anlernen* bedeutet schlicht *in einen Beruf einarbeiten*. Das ist wohl etwas, was jeder Mensch irgendwann mal durchmacht und ist somit keinesfalls negativ.

Comment: 'Jemanden anlernen' Es wird hauptsächlich im Bereich Arbeitswelt benutzt. Es kann auch eine negative Konnotation tragen, wenn man von 'angelernten Kräften' spricht und damit   'nur gering für diese Arbeit qualifiziertes Personal' meint, im Gegensatz zu 'gelernten' oder 'ausgebildeten' Fachkräften. Das Präfix 'an' kann hier als *'nur leicht/teilweise/beginnend'* verstanden werden.

Comment: I'd also say that "belehren" has a negative touch to it. It is mostly used downward in a hierarchy in a commanding manner, if you've done something wrong or if you are being made aware of negative consequences of wrong behavior.

Comment: Bin bei euch mit dem negativen Kontext von "belehren" *ausserhalb des öffentlichen Rechts- und Rechtsvollzugssystems* - Da das Wort hauptsächlich in diesem Bereich zuhause ist (und dort einen durchaus neutralen Wert besitzt), ist die Annahme, dass jemand, der nicht Bestandteil dieses Systems ist und trotzdem *belehrt*, sich "zuviel herausnimmt", durchaus valide.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that "belehren" is "(trying) to teach without being asked to"?

"Belehren" can easily be really unwanted and make the person exposed to it feel annoyed, as there is no desire to receive that kind of 'teaching'.  It's  actually the definition of "spam"...

However, like in a case of "Rechtsbelehrung" for example, it might be very useful to the one that gets "belehrt", even though they may not like it very much in the moment.